# Delete row from MySQL table in java program

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hii geeks i am little stuck at my code, i ll be very thankful  if you people can help me in solving this
This is my **Java Program** and i am using  **2 SQL Queries** in a single code
One query is to **Select data from table** and other query is **Deleting a row from table** but deleting a row or even deleting a whole record is not working...Plzz help me..This is my piece of code

```
try{

        String Query = "select * from ImageData ";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            Path[i]=rs.getString(1);
            i++;

        } 
        conn.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Delete");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AB) {
            try{
                String query1 = "DELETE FROM ImageData";
                PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);

                ps1.executeUpdate();

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: `catch(Exception e){}` Your code is swallowing exceptions - instead you should deal with them, such as print the stack trace `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Printing the exception you're catching may clue you (and us!) in to what the problem is.

Comment: is the connection available? as i can see you are closing the connection after select query.

Comment: thanx! it worked @copeg

Comment: Yup..that was an error , i fixed it later.. @Rishaldevsingh

Comment: As it worked for you , Please do post and let us know how it got resolved so that other can also get the benefit :)

Comment: yup sure...i posted it in the comment below the answer...Whole code that i posted is same except that conn.close() was wrong and i passed e.printstatcktrace in the exceptions block..and hence it worked @Rishaldevsingh

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ps1.execute();

```
    try{

        String Query = "select * from ImageData ";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            Path[i]=rs.getString(1);
            i++;

        } 
        conn.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Delete");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AB) {
            try{
                String query1 = "DELETE FROM ImageData";
                PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);

                ps1.execute();

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: ps1.executeupdate() worked..Error was that Code was ignoring exception condition, hence i passed "e.printStackstrace"..and it worked..bdw Thanx for the help